# UIGestureRecognizer Store in NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I've researched everywhere but can't find the answer. How would you convert UIGestures in NSData and Convert it back to UIGestures when you need it?

Is it possible to send UIGestures via Bluetooth to another device?

Thanks.

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: Very interesting question. I wonder if you could save the order of touches. It would get even more interesting when you consider multitouch and the parallel states it creates.

Comment: Yeah, hopefully someone more creative than myself, is capable of resolving this issue. I am very interested to know if this is possible. I have tried it in  various ways such as this NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&gestureRecognizer length: sizeof(gestureRecognizer)]; but first of all i don't think my syntax is correct, but it would be nice if something like this would be possible. Hopefully someone can answer this.

Comment: `UIGestureRecognizer` doesn't conform to `NSCoding`, plus serializing a gesture recognizer really doesn't make much sense, you would be better off saving the data needed to recreate a same one.

Comment: Maybe you can store not the recognizer but the changes that it produces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gesterrecognizers is an object that holds pointers to other objects your objects plus system objects so seralizing the recognizer will not bring back the system objects that it will need to come back. If it was not tied to system frameworks it would be a straight creation. So the only thing you could do is save the data needed to recreate a new recognizer.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are trying or want to implement is not possible in any case. You can't Store  or Convert the `UIGestureRecognizer`. Its Impossible.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. They are all helpful! I like sEnC's answer. Maybe storing the changes it produces is the way to go with what i'm trying to do. Love this community and you guys are very helpful. Keep up the good work! I'll give it a try and what i find out, i'll post it here to benefit everyone that is curious.

Comment: So i got the solution. Unfortunately as many of you have stated, as of right now, there is no way to store or convert gestures in NSData, however, i was able to get what i wanted to do by storing the touches and CGPoints in NSData which is what i was looking all along but i had the wrong approach.

Comment: @Binky Thats good you got the solution right but you have not mentioned in the Question that you need to store paths of Touches. I think u want to store Drawing & need it to open anytime when required am i right ?

Comment: You are right. I did not mention that, but actually in a way that is what i did.